# By mistake i update a table without putting where condition. Now i want all previous record in table. How Can i get back all rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL server,  I update a table using query without putting where condition.
Now i want all previous record in table. How Can i get back all rows.
This query executed directly without any Transaction used.

Comment: Restore from backup.

Comment: I don't have any Backup for this Table.

Comment: Then you don't have a production database. If you don't care enough about a database that you make backups of it, why do you care that it contains wrong data?

Comment: Since you don't have a backup, you need a good memory or good deduction skills because now you gotta go back and edit all those rows and update the right values in there manually.

Comment: do you have a backup of your server ? Do you have a paper version of your data ?

Comment: means? all data on paper so that i can enter in database?

Comment: Any old copy of the data you might have, a printout, screenshots of the application. You need to start updating the rows to set the columns back to their old values before your update. If you don't want to rely on your memory, do you have anything else that can help you?

Comment: This is below data of last previous row value with column name which i have.   shown below                                                                                         ExeVersionID VersionDate             FirstValue SecondValue ThirdValue ForthValue Remarks
305                  2014-12-22 18:45:03.870 1 0                    6                                     30           SCR 8009,8040,8117,8123

Comment: Unfortunately, this is what's known as "a learning experience". Usually after one or two of these you'll adopt practices that lead to more caution - such as only running experimental scripts against copies of the database until you're happy that the script does what it should. And, of course, getting a proper backup regime in place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three things you can do here.

**Option 1: Do a full restore from a backup**

This will reset the database back to a previous point in time. Anything you modified in the database after this will be lost.

**Option 2: Do a full restore from a backup and replay your transaction logs**

This will first do the same as option 1, but then replay all modifications you did in the database after that backup. Obviously you would only replay the transaction logs up until right before the point where you messed up.

**Option 3: Start piecing together the data manually**

Here you basically have to go back and update the rows with "new" old data. Any source for this data you might have will be invaluable here, like a printout, screenshots, memory, etc.

---

Since you've already said you don't have a backup you now have 3 tasks ahead of you:

1. Start backing up your database
2. Learn a trick when it comes to updating your database
3. Option 3 above, piece together the data manually, updating the rows back to their old values, as far as possible

---

**Trick: How to update the database when you're afraid of messing up**

You basically write your SQL script like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT ... anything you need to verify that the update has NOT taken place

UPDATE ... your update statement (or DELETE, INSERT, etc.)

SELECT ... anything you need to verify that the update HAS taken place

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

When doing it this way you can experiment, as long as you don't specifically select a piece of SQL in Management Studio and execute only that. When you've verified that everything is correct, including messages telling you how many rows where updated/deleted/inserted, then you replace `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` with `COMMIT TRANSACTION` and actually save the changes.